# how to use curent date in image path django

Tags: python, django

I'm writing my news web-site and I already have translit widget imported into my django models.py

and it's looks like

```
class Article(models.Model):
    class Meta():
        db_table = "article"
        verbose_name = "Новость"
        verbose_name_plural = "Новости"

    def get_image_path(self, filename):
         path = ''.join(["static/article/", translit.slugify(filename)])
    return path

    article_image1 = models.ImageField(upload_to= get_image_path, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name = "Фотография 1")
```

In that case all uploaded images are stored in path_to_app/static/article/some_image_name.jpg
But we have a lot of images and storing them in one folder is very problematicaly.

**the problem is:**

How can I save image to

path_to_app/static/article/todays_year/todays_month/todays_date/some_image_name.jpg

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [datetime.date.strftime()](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.strftime) function.

```
from datetime import date

def get_image_path(self, filename):
     path = ''.join([date.today().strftime('static/article/%Y/%m/%d/'),
                     translit.slugify(filename)])
     return path
```

Answer (score 0):

You can return a string from your `upload_to` function - in this case `get_image_path`, with the date-formatters in it, and Django will pass the date information to the string. (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.FileField.upload_to)